# vscodeのターミナルが文字化けする

Tags: 文字化け, vscode

windows 10 pro
vscode バージョン　1.25.1

vscodeのターミナルで日本語が文字化けします。ユーザー設定で `"files.autoGuessEncoding": true` としたのですが直りません。どうすればいいのでしょうか。
プログラミング初心者なので変なこと言ってたらすみません。

### 追記

`"files.encoding": "shiftjis"`を追記してみたらエディタもターミナルも文字化けしました。

[image: 文字化けしている様子のスクリーンショットです]

`"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["-NoExit","chcp 65001"]`を設定に追加すると文字が出力されませんでした。

[image: 設定を変えると出力がでなくなった様子のスクリーンショットです]

ちゃんと動くプログラムと動かないプログラムがあります。
[image: 動くプログラムの例です]

3枚目の画像の"\n"をendlに変えても大丈夫です。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

また、ついさっきから新しくプログラムを書こうとしたら、iostream file not foundというような表示が出されます。それでも正しくコンパイルされて実行されます。英字は出力されますが日本語は出力されません。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 3枚目のスクリーンショットで、`"\n"` の部分を `endl` に変えるとどうなりますでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

"files.autoGuessEncoding"・"files.encoding" の設定はファイルのエンコードを決定するもので、
ターミナルのエンコードを設定するものではありません。

- 解決策１
  ターミナルのPowershellの文字コードを変更します。
  文字コードを変更するにはchcpコマンドを使用します。
  UTF-8に変更するには`chcp 65001`を実行します。
  sjisに変更するには`chcp 932`を実行します。
  各文字コードの割り当て番号については[マイクロソフトのドキュメント](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/desktop/Intl/code-page-identifiers)を確認してください。
  `chcp`コマンドを手で入力せずに、起動時に自動的に実行されるようにするには
  設定ファイルに`"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["-NoExit","chcp 65001"]`と記載してください。
- 解決策2
  PowershellはSJIS・UTF-8BOM・UTF-16のファイルであれば設定を変更せずに読み込めます。
  読み込むファイルのエンコードを変更します。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
下のバーの文字コードの部分をクリックし、エンコード付きで保存→保存したい文字コードを選択

Answer (score 2):

MinGW64 GCCを使用しているという前提で話します。Visual Studio (Visual C++)の場合はまた事情が異なります。

---

混乱しないように`"files.encoding"`、 `"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows"`、 `"files.autoGuessEncoding"`の設定は全て削除し、Visual Studio Codeを再起動しておいてください。

ソースコードは**UTF-8**にしてください(Visual C++でもコンパイルしたい、PowerShell上でソースコードを見たいと言った場合は、**UTF-8 with BOM**にしてください)。あとはコンパイル時に`-fexec-charset=CP932`オプションを付けることでうまくいきます(gccとg++ともに)。

```
g++ -fexec-charset=CP932 hello.cpp
```

---

以下、解説です。

C/C++には標準の文字コードと言ったものは存在しません。そのため、コンパイル時に正しい文字コードを指定しないとうまく動作しない場合があります。ややこしいのが、三つの文字コードが別々に使われると言うことです。それらは次の通りです。

1. ソースコード自身の文字コード
2. コンパイルされたバイナリ上での文字列リテラル(`"..."`)の文字コード
3. コンパイルされたバイナリ上でのワイド文字列リテラル(`L"..."`)の文字コード

1.から2.や3へはコンパイラが文字コードを自動的に変換します。これらの文字コードが何であるかは環境やコンパイラによって違います。

MinGW64 GCCの場合

1. UTF-8 (BOM付きの場合も可)
2. UTF-8
3. UTF-16LE

Visual C++の場合

1. ファイルの先頭にBOMがない場合はロケール依存(日本語ならCP932)
   ファイルの先頭にBOMがある場合はBOMによる自動判別(UTF-8、UTF-16LE、UTF-16BE)
2. ロケール依存(日本語ならCP932)
3. UTF-16LE

もう一つ注意すべき事は`printf`や`iostream`等の動作です。これらは文字列(`char *`)を扱いますが、ロケールによって文字コード変換するという動作はおこなわず、データをそのまま出力します。そのため、文字列自体の文字コードと出力先の文字コードが合っていなければ、文字化けなどが発生することになります。(ワイド文字列の出力はロケールに合わせて文字コード変換等が行われる場合があります)

そして、Visual Studio Codeの統合ターミナルでのPowerShellも文字コードをもっており、デフォルトはロケール依存(日本語ならCP932)となっています。つまり、文字化けの原因は、2.のコンパイルされたバイナリ上での文字列リテラルの文字コードとターミナルでの文字コードが一致していないと言うことです。

GCCではコンパイル時にこの三つの文字コードを指定できます。問題になっている2.の文字コードを日本語のPoweShellの文字コードであるCP932に指定するのが、`-fexec-charset=CP932`になります。

【補足】

- CP932はWindowsで使われるShfit_JISの亜種です。MS932やWindows-31Jという別名で言われることもあります。
- PowerShell側をUTF-8にするという方法もあります。`chcp 65001`がそのコマンドです。
- ソースコードがShift_JISでもコンパイルできることがありますが、壊れたUTF-8として扱っているだけに過ぎません。特に`'表'`のような2バイト目が`\`である文字があるとコンパイルエラーになったりします。
- C11/C++11から追加された`u8"..."`リテラルは上記の指定と関係無くUTF-8のリテラルになります。文字列リテラルを環境に依存せずにUTF-8に強制させたいときに便利です。
- `char *`そのものには文字コード情報という物が存在しない事に注意してください。

Answer (score 0):

ユーザー設定で、デフォールトの文字エンコードを utf-8 から、お使いのファイルで使っている文字エンコードに変更してみてください。

例えば、デフォールトを Shift-JIS にしたければ、「"files.autoGuessEncoding": true」の行の後に以下の行を追加してください。

> "files.encoding": "shiftjis",